# Using chromedp to render PNG object from HTML string

Tags: chromedp

I am very new to Chromedp. I know how to render image from an url for Chromdp but is there a way to render it from a HTML string itself using Chromedp? I am able to convert an url to image using the following:

```
func fullScreenshot(urlstr string, quality int64, res *[]byte) chromedp.Tasks {
    return chromedp.Tasks{
        chromedp.Navigate(urlstr),
        chromedp.Sleep(3 * time.Second),
        chromedp.ActionFunc(func(ctx context.Context) error {
            // get layout metrics
            _, _, contentSize, err := page.GetLayoutMetrics().Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            width, height := int64(math.Ceil(contentSize.Width)), int64(math.Ceil(contentSize.Height))

            // force viewport emulation
            err = emulation.SetDeviceMetricsOverride(width, height, 1, false).
                WithScreenOrientation(&emulation.ScreenOrientation{
                    Type:  emulation.OrientationTypePortraitPrimary,
                    Angle: 0,
                }).
                Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }

            // capture screenshot
            *res, err = page.CaptureScreenshot().
                WithQuality(quality).
                WithClip(&page.Viewport{
                    X:      contentSize.X,
                    Y:      contentSize.Y,
                    Width:  contentSize.Width,
                    Height: contentSize.Height,
                    Scale:  1,
                }).Do(ctx)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            return nil
        }),
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Could you share code examples of that? What specific issues are you facing?

Comment: My issue is how to use Chromedp to take ina html string and render an image instead of having to navigate to an url

Comment: @SalilKanetkar Did you find a solution I am also stuck with same use case